# maximum number of rows that can be shown on tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.1

I would like know the limit of maximum number of rows that can be shown in the UItableView. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe there is a limit?

Comment: @Eriko: i am expecting to insert around 3k rows(Text only, with index). So want to know what are the complication that could come up.

Comment: I've wrapped it up in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be no maximum. You don't insert actively anyway, you just implement the delegate methods to serve the cells - they are not loaded all at once if done properly.

Just having tried it with one thousand custom cells, it worked without a problem. But with 3k even with index it is a lot to scroll, I'd consider putting them into a navigation hierarchy (but this heavily depends on your use).

One more thing: Make sure to be efficient when drawing the cells, i.e. implement drawRect: instead of cluttering the cells with labels, views etc., this will make scrolling much faster.

Comment: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to allocate data stores for 9223372036854775807 rows in section 0. Consider using fewer rows' I Was curious and came across this.

Answer (score 10):

This [Cocoa with Love blog](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/optimizing-loading-of-very-large-table.html) post is very informative - it looks at the performance of a table view with thousands of cells.

The question is whether it has some internal hard limit - it's seemingly enough for most needs - the above post concludes:

> The iPhone can handle tables with 100,000 rows — and it continues to scroll as smoothly as though it were only 100 rows.

Comment: The article also mentions that past 800,000 row of height 44, the single precision float(32 bit platform) used for cell positioning fails (== loses precision and you get partially overlapped cells).

Answer (score 2):

You will ultimately be limited by the fact that all the methods such as numberOfRowsInSectiin take integer arguments but hopefully you won't need to approach those limits :)

Answer (score 0):

In `numberofRawInSection` delegate method we are generally return count of array which is Int type, so maximum number of rows that can be shown on tableview's section = `Int.max`

So let say capacity "C"

`C = (maximum number of section) X (maximum number of item in section)`